# unfamiliar gain equation of differential amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential, gain

I am examining op amps and I found this pdf very helpful: http://www.aicdesign.org/SCNOTES/2010notes/Lect2UP230_(100327).pdf

In this tutorial,  the op amp circuit topology is given as this:
[image: op amp topology]

and gains of stages of the op amp are given like this:

[image: gain equations]

First time I see an equation like this. I thought the (DC)gain of the first stage is: \$gm_{2} * r_{ds2} // r_{ds4}\$

it seems really wrong to me. Can anyone explain why the gain is represented that way in this tutorial?

Comment: can you specify the page no. of this tutorial in above pdf

Comment: on page number 4.

Comment: @Alperözel  hope my explanation helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gds = 1/rds => conductance add up when you have parallel resistances.

G = 1/R

R1 || R2 = 1 / (G1 +G2)

Thus, rds2 || rds4 = 1/ [(gds2 + gds4) ]

So, GAIN for the first stage;

Av = gm2 * (rds2 || rs4) = gm2 / (gds2 + gds4)

here since  m1 and m2 are differential pairs ,its ok to assume that their
 trans conductances are almost same (gm1 =gm2).

Part2:

Regarding the expression in terms of current ,

The drain resistance (rd) is due to channel length modulation and is given by :

rds = 1/ (lambda * Id) or gds = ( lambda * Id).

So replacing gds, we get;

Av= gm2 / [lambda*(Id2 + Id4) ]